# React 16: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

```
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
```

Throwing error when test cases executed with Jest + Enzyme library

Answer (score 0):

You need to updated the babel.config.js file with the below code inside the plugins section

```
plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs", {
      "allowTopLevelThis": true
    }]
```

Comment: I'm using @craco/craco instead of babel then how I can solve this problem ?