# Error while Jest setup for Snapshots - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, snapshot

I'm going to create snapshot test, but got problems in the beginning.

I got such error while running test:

```
/Users/illia/WebstormProjects/TESTS/src/components/PaymentDisclaimer/PaymentDisclaimer.test.js:3
    import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
    ^^^^^^
```

The code in test file:

```
'use strict';

import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import PaymentDisclaimer from './PaymentDisclaimer';

it('renders correctly when all default props', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<PaymentDisclaimer fullPrice={9} />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Packages:

```
"jest": "28.1.0",    
"react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
"ts-jest": "^29.0.1",

node -v 12.18.3 (change node version is one of the last options, if it's possible)
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73026699/react-16-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module), but it didin't help

This is only one error, but earlier i got another one, very similar:
in the component PaymentDisclaimer we use component from the external library. And I got an error 'Cannot use import statement outside a module' for this case too.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "qqq",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "www",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf build",
    "json-validate": "node cli/localizationValidate.js",
    "prestart": "node cli/validation.js",
    "build": "npm run prestart && webpack --mode production --config ./config/webpack.prod.js --progress",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --progress --config  ./config/webpack.dev.js",
    "lint": "node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx --rule 'no-console: ['error', { allow: ['warn', 'error', 'info'] }]'",
    "lint-fix": "node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js '*/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}' --fix",
    "lint-staged": "prettier --write src/**/*.css && node_modules/stylelint/bin/stylelint.js stylelint src/**/*.css",
    "lint-staged-fix": "prettier --write src/**/*.css && node_modules/stylelint/bin/stylelint.js stylelint --fix src/**/*.css",
    "mr-tests": "npm run lint",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "node_modules/core-components/.+\\.(j|t)sx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!core-components/.*)"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/env",
      "@babel/react",
      "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "jsx-control-statements",
      [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
        {
          "regenerator": true
        }
      ],
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
        {
          "allowTopLevelThis": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sentry/react": "6.19.7",
    "@sentry/tracing": "6.19.7",
    "@solidgate/react-sdk": "1.2.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.3.3",
    "axios": "0.21.1",
    "classnames": "2.3.1",
    "dayjs": "1.10.6",
    "formik": "2.2.9",
    "i18next": "19.9.2",
    "i18next-icu": "2.0.3",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "3.2.2",
    "intl-messageformat": "9.11.4",
    "jsonschema": "1.4.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-compound-timerv2": "2.0.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-hotjar": "3.0.1",
    "react-i18next": "11.12.0",
    "react-lazyload": "3.2.0",
    "react-modal": "3.14.3",
    "react-phone-input-2": "2.15.0",
    "react-qr-code": "2.0.2",
    "react-redux": "7.2.5",
    "react-router": "5.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.0",
    "react-slick": "0.28.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "react-toastify": "8.1.0",
    "redux": "4.1.1",
    "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "1.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "reselect": "4.1.5",
    "slick-carousel": "1.8.1",
    "solid-payment": "1.5.2-dev",
    "testania": "0.2.0-dev",
    "core-analytics": "1.4.4",
    "core-components": "1.2.2",
    "yup": "0.29.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.15.5",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "7.15.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.15.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.15.0",
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "1.8.1",
    "@svgr/webpack": "5.5.0",
    "@types/node": "14.17.15",
    "@types/react": "17.0.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.14",
    "@types/react-lazyload": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.18",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-jsx-control-statements": "4.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "6.4.1",
    "cross-env": "7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "4.3.0",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "dotenv-webpack": "7.0.3",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "6.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-control-statements": "2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.25.1",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "2.5.4",
    "file-loader": "6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.5.2",
    "http-server": "0.12.3",
    "husky": "8.0.0",
    "jest": "28.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.10.1",
    "node-notifier": "9.0.1",
    "postcss": "8.3.6",
    "postcss-discard-comments": "5.0.1",
    "prettier": "2.1.2",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "4.13.0",
    "style-loader": "1.3.0",
    "stylelint": "14.5.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "5.3.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "9.2.7",
    "tsx-control-statements": "4.1.1",
    "typescript": "4.4.2",
    "typescript-plugin-css-modules": "3.4.0",
    "url-loader": "4.1.0",
    "util": "0.12.4",
    "webpack": "5.52.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.9.0",
    "webpack-cli": "4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "4.8.1",
    "webpack-merge": "5.8.0"
  }
}
```

jest-config

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/core-components'],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsConfig: {
                target: 'ES2019',
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Comment: Can you post your `package.json` file? Do you have a `babel.config.js` and a `jest.config.js` file? Have you installed `babel-jest`?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I added info in description. And I don't have babel-jest